# Mentioning roles in slash command reply discors.js BOT

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot using discord js v13.2.0, and I want to reply to an interaction with a mention to an role, but when the interaction is "sent", it not ping the role.

I am just a beginner in code so maybe I do something wrong, I tried looking on the internet but I found nothing.

```js
    async execute(interaction, client) {
      interaction.reply({
        "content": "This is the role mention  : <@&roleid>"
      })

    },
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnYO4.png)

Answer (score 1):

To allow mentions in interaction you can use [`allowedMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.2.0/typedef/BaseMessageOptions):

```js
interaction.reply({
    allowedMentions: {roles: ['YOUR_ROLE_ID']},
    content: "This is the role mention: <@&roleid>"
})
```